# Obfuscating Email addresses with Javascript - split - reverse - join (Beginner)

Tags: javascript, email

Thank you for your time.

I'm trying to build a simple script to reverse email addresses as strings so I can use them for visible email addresses, email mailto: links & addresses for the "action" parameter in forms etc... to help avoid simple scraper bots.

I've tried a multitude of different methods and I'm probably just too inept at js to get them working. Here's a partially working sample of what I think would be an ideal situation.

The data I want does show up in the console log but I'm having trouble getting it to show up in any of the html. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<script>
  var contact = "moc.etis@tcatnoc";

  function reverseString(str) {
    return str.split('').reverse().join('');
    document.getElementById('showemail').innerHTML = 'contact';
  }
  console.log(reverseString(contact));
</script>

<span id="showemail"></span>
<a href="javascript:reverseString('contact');"> Contact </a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onload="reverseString(contact);"> Contact </a>
```

Comment: `return` will exit the `reverseString` before `document.getElementById` runs. Remove that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question, but if i try to run the code i have as output 'contact'(reversed). Are you wondering how to print the original string?

In that case i think will work ->

```
var contact = "moc.etis@tcatnoc";

      
    function reverseString(str) {
       str =  str.split('').reverse().join('');
       document.getElementById('showemail').innerHTML = str;
  }
      
      console.log(reverseString(contact));
    </script>

    <span id="showemail"></span>
    <a href="javascript:reverseString(contact);"> Contact </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onload="reverseString(contact);"> Contact </a>
```

Comment: I don't know if you were asking this :)

Comment: The `reverseString` still returns before `document.getElementById` runs

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand. Can you make an output example? :(

Comment: Maybe like that? (Code edited)

Comment: I'm basically just trying to show the output of the reverseString function in HTML. You can the 3 methods I tried to render a link using the reversed email address. The console.log line is just there to confirm that the string "moc.etis@tcatnoc" is being reversed.